# Remove decimal values from a value of type double or numeric in obiee rpd

Tags: double, numeric, administration, obiee, repository-design

I'm working on obiee 12c rpd. I have a measure column in my physical table in DB with bigint data type. In physical layer of rpd, I've chosen its data type as numeric because int data type is so small for my values. Because of numeric data type, it's added '.00' at the end of my values. I used to remove them with round function in BMM layer's expression builder but it didn't work. I tried this steps with Changing the numeric to double data type in physical layer but I got the same result means I see values with .00 at the end in my dashboards.

Now I'm going to remove these zeros in rpd.
Is it possible?  How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the answers above. If that doesn't seem to work, you could try to change the format to custom and work with a mask as explained here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/bi.1111/e10544/format.htm#BIEUG10831

Answer (score 0):

From oracle doc:

> ```
> JDBC and the Administration Tool do not support this type (BIG INT);
> ```
>
> therefore, Oracle BI EE does not fully support the BIG INT type.  BI
>   Server does offer some support for this type,  but BIG INT has not
>   been thoroughly tested with Oracle BI Server.  The BIG INT type is
>   intended to be same as the C int64 data type.
>   Link:https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10540/data_types.htm#BIEMG4602

Making it DOUBLE and sort the .00 issue inside the answers solves your problem ?
Go to column properties and data format, here is the window:
[image]

Comment: Thanks but I want to know is there any way to remove decimal part through functions or expressions while designing the rpd?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how OBI works. The RPD is the number crunching engine. NOT the visualization part.

If you want the decimals to be hidden by default, then you set the data format with zero decimals by default. That's how the tool works. Not in the RPD.